# Real time image processing timing

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, arduino, sensors

I am using Arduino controller with MATLAB to build a system that reads in sensor data, which triggers a live feed camera to capture an image for real time image processing. Based on these results further processing is done "after some required delay" through controller. Now the problem I am facing is I cannot read sensor data until the last step of previous stage is completed. I want to be able to read sensor data continuosly and process images even while the last processing stage based on previous image is still executing (because of the delay provided). Thank you for any advice/help. Sorry if my english is bad I hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about executing a Matlab code in asynchronous mode. As this maybe hard to control using parallel processes generated by matlabpool (e.g. parfor), you may consider writing your code as [MPI](http://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/cybersec/softwaretools/matlabmpi/matlabmpi.html). Through MPI you can assign the code lines to be run on each slave process while merging/timing the results can be controlled by the master process.